# Export python dictionary contaning list values into Excel sheet

Tags: python, dictionary, xlwt

Below is my sample dictionary.

```
dict1 = {'X':[['a','1'], ['b','3'], ['c','2']],
         'Y':[['a','8'], ['b','13']],
         'Z':[['a','5'], ['b','7'], ['f','8']]}
```

I am trying to get the below output in excel sheet using xlwt module.

```
X    a       1
     b       3
     c       2

Y    a       8
     b      13

Z    a       5
     b       7
     f       8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict1` won't preserve its order when writing the keys/values to the excel file, but one option may be to put the contents in an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) then write each entry to rows, columns in the excel file:

```
import collections
# save order in dict1 to OrderedDict 
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

row = 0
for key in od.iterkeys():
    # write the key
    sheet.write(row, 0, key)
    for values in od[key]:
        for column, value in enumerate(values):
        # write each of this key's values in this row's columns    
        sheet.write(row, column+1, value)
        row += 1
```

Other than blank lines between the keys, it appears to match your desired output:
 [image]

Comment: Thanks @davedwards